# Is there an easy way to flatten a json:api response on Android?

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, json-api

I'm trying to flatten the below response without having to parse it into a class. The reason for this is that the server could add or remove fields at anytime so it needs to be dynamic. We also have another service that returns lookup paths that we use to get data out of the flattened response - like "$.detail.att_one" There is a library for iOS that does the exact thing I'm looking for but as far as I can find nothing similar for Android: https://github.com/infinum/Japx

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "type": "items",
        "id": "14",
        "attributes": {
            "item_type": "shape_circle",
            "code": null,
            "size": "70"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "detail": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "circle",
                    "id": "90"
                }
            },
            "metadata": {
                "data": "metadata"
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http://url/item/14"
        }
    }
],
"included": [
    {
        "type": "circle",
        "id": "90",
        "attributes": {
            "att_one": 4,
            "att_two": "11111111111",
            "att_three": "Bob"
        }
    }
]}
```

The result I'm looking for:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "14",
        "type": "items",
        "item_type": "shape_circle",
        "code": null,
        "size": "70",
        "metadata": {
            "data": "metadata"
        },
        "detail": {
            "type": "circle",
            "id": "90",
            "att_one": 4,
            "att_two": "11111111111",
            "att_three": "Bob"
        },
        "links": {
            "self": "http://url/item/14"
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Do you know how OkHttp or Retrofit library works? take a look into them and how they use serialization with Gson or Moshi.

Comment: Yeah I'm already using Retrofit and Moshi to get the response from the server. I could create a class with @Json fields that correspond to the fields in the response but I want to avoid that as I want to be able to pass the raw json around, but only once it has been flattened to be like the result above

Comment: So you dont want to serialize the response? Use JSON library to receive the JSON object and then pass it around.

Comment: Yeah thats what I want to do, my problem is flattening the json to merge the included to be in the format I'm looking for (the last json code block in my question), and then also being able to un-flatten it so I can send it back up to the server

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice JSONAPI library that does the thing, but you have to define resource classes for it.

Check out [jasminb/jsonapi-converter](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter)

It recursively flattens all the included relationships and handles inheritance.